# $f_1,f_2 :\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be two functions such that...

Tags: calculus, functions, proof-verification

Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be  two functions on $ \mathbb{R}^2$ defined as  :

$$f_1(x,y)=(x+1,y+3)\\ f_2(x,y)=(x-3,y-2)$$

Which of the following are true?

- For any positive integer $k$ there exists a unique $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f_1^k(0,0)=f_2^k(a,b)$
- For any real number $\alpha$ and any positive integer, there is atmost one solution of $y$ for $f_1^k(0,0)=f_2^k(\alpha,y)$
- There exists $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f_1^k(a,b)\neq f_2^k(x,y)$ for any $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and for any positive $k$
- $f_1$ is a linear transformation.

By $f^k$ i mean $f\circ f\circ\cdots\circ f$ ($k$ times)

I could immediately see that $f_1$ is non linear

we have $f_1^k(x,y)=(x+k,y+3k)$  and $f_2^k(x,y)=(x-3k,y-2k)$

$f_1^k(0,0)=(k,3k)$ and $f_2^k(a,b)=(a-3k,b-2k)$

For $f_1^k(0,0)=f_2^k(a,b)$ we have $(k,3k)=(a-3k,b-2k)$ i.e., $a=4k$ and $b=5k$ and thus $a,b$ are fixed. First bullet is correct.

For $f_1^k(0,0)=f_2^k(\alpha,y)$ we have $(k,3k)=(\alpha-3k,y-2k)$ this imply $y=5k$ which is unique. Thus second bullet is true.

For $f_1^k(a,b)\neq f_2^k(x,y)$ we have $(a+k,b+3k)\neq (x-3k,y-2k)$ which can be easily seen to be false.

I would be thankful if some of you could  make sure if my justification is sufficient/clear.

Thank You

Comment: $f_1^k(x,y)=(x+k,y+3k)$ or $f_1(x,y)=(x+1,y+2)$

Comment: there is a typo.. I am clearing it... Thank you  :)

Comment: other that this,it's ok.

Comment: are you saying this is true ...